# Using while loop to make user input only an existing user

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to make it that if the user inputs a non existing user they would be asked to retry again, but it is the opposite effect. I am sure it is something wrong with my while condition I just cant see :(

code:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "Name of the username: " 
read username 
while id -u $username >/dev/null 2>&1;
do 
echo "User doesn't exist"
echo -n "Name of the username: "
read username
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to negate the condition with `!`.

Remember that `while cond` means execute while `cond` is true; it is the opposite of `until cond` (execute until `cond` is true).

`until` exists in many languages, including any POSIX-compliant shell; the negation will always work, however.